# mongodb query returns [object Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongo with NODEJS, but while trying to get data from db, there is always an object it returns [object Object] instead of object;
Here is my Schema

```
IngredientSchema = new MongoDb.Schema(
    {
        "name": String  //名称
        ,"optional":Boolean
        ,"substitution": String
        ,"preparation": String
        , "amount": Number
        , "units": String   //单位
    }
);

directionSchema = new MongoDb.Schema(
    {
        "image": String     //图片
        ,"tip": String
        , "content": String //正文
        , "duration": Number    //定时 无定时则设置为null
        , "audiopath": String
    }
);

infoSchema =  {
    "title": String //菜谱名称
    ,"lang": String
    ,"author":String
    ,"image_url": String
    ,"serves": Number
    ,"source": String
    ,"time":Number
};

categorySchema = {
    "region": String
    ,"type": String
    ,"tags": String
};

CookBookSchema= new MongoDb.Schema(
    {
        "info": infoSchema
        , "categories": categorySchema
        , "ingredients": [IngredientSchema] //材料
        , "directions": [directionSchema]       //步骤
        ,'nutrition':String
    }
    , {strict: false}
);
CookBook= MongoDb.model(COOKBOOK_TABLE, CookBookSchema);
```

it returns value like this

```
[
    {
        "categories": "[object Object]",
        ....
    }
]
```

The other object in result works fine.
I searched in google but can't find the answer

In mongodb the "categories" data is like this

```
categories" : { "type" : "cake", "tags" : "Cake, Caramel Sauce, Chocolate Cake, Chocolate Cake, Chocolate Desserts, Christmas, Christmas Cake, Christmas Desserts, Christmas Party, Coconuts, Desserts, Fruit, German Chocolate Cake, Healthy Cooking, Ice Cream Toppings, Low Sodium, More Fruits, More Holidays, Sauces and Toppings, Valentine's Day" }
```

But it lack of an _id object which other objects will have

i wrote into mongodb using codes below

```

```
cookBookModule.create(data, function(err, object) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                console.log(data);
                return res.status(HTTPCODE.DB_ERR).json('save failed');
            }

            res.status(HTTPCODE.CREATED).json(object);
            TtsModule.audio_process(object);
        })
```

```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify()` method to see what your `[object object]` contains.

Comment: yes i did. I printed it with JSON.stringify(). This is not the matter. It just return a string, not an object

Comment: Use "util" Package to view the object..

Comment: How to? never used utile

Comment: I don't use Mongoose but shouldn't it be `categorySchema = new MongoDb.Schema({...})`?

Comment: nope I am sure about this, cause schema can only use a ref or array, category is not an array so it shell be a ref.

Answer (score 1):

```
"categories": "[object Object]"
```

This means that when you stored the object, you actually stored the `toString()` representation of it. As there was none, you got the default `[object Object]`

Your issue is not on the reading from the database, but on the writing, check how your categories are being serialized into mongo.

Comment: you are right,But when I looked into Mongodb, the "category" is an object, But it's strange that usually objects in Mongo will have an _id object, but this one has none. and also i use Module.create(data, function(err, object){...});Is there anything needs attention?

Comment: what is inside the data? that's what you should be looking at. Categories don't output an _id because they are inside your cookbook, so the cookbook will have the ID.